# Issue with tab-separated data containing double quotes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data file .txt. But some record is just wrong fomat

```
id name code country \
0  "hoa" 111 vietnam
1  "thang(tab) " 123 vietnam
```

When I use bulk insert to import file to SQL Server, the double quotes jump to the "code" column (I think this error is about the tab). Like this:

| id | name | code | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "hoa" | 111 | vietnam |
| 1 | "thang | " | 123 |

This is my bulk insert code

```sql
    SET @SQL = 'BULK INSERT #GL055_BRN
    FROM ''F:\d.txt''
    WITH (
    DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
    )';
    EXEC(@SQL)
```

I want my table to be like this:

| id | name | code | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "hoa" | 111 | vietnam |
| 1 | "thang" | 123 | vietnam |

How to fix this problem? Thanks all.

Comment: You want to keep double quotes too?

Comment: add `FIELDQUOTE='"'`

Comment: @DaleK im sorry, i will edit right now

Comment: @eshirvana  seems to be the default?

Comment: @SalmanA It's much more better if  the double quotes are removed

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2017 or later? I would suggest reading the `FORMAT='CSV'` section of the [`BULK INSERT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#format--csv), but be aware that the quotes are part of the encoding, not part of the data, so you shouldn't expect to retain the surrounding quotes in the table.

Comment: @eshirvana there are more fields behind but i just decribe 3, sr, my bad, let me edit this

Comment: @DaleK seems like it.

Comment: @eshirvana it sill split by FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'' first